# How to access mobile phone browser cookies

Tags: android, ios, cookies

Is it possible to access all browser cookies or any other navigation data of a smartphone from android or ios apps using react native, java or swift/objective-C ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not possible in any language.  Browsers (and there's more than one of them on Android) are their own separate apps, and have their own private storage.  They do not give up the values of their cookies to any other apps, and doing so would be a major privacy violation as it would allow a 3rd party app to see the data stored by a webapp and manipulate it, which could include being able to send API requests as you to a website without your knowledge.  So no API will ever be made to allow that.

Now if you're talking about a WebView inside your app (basically a part of your app that displays html)-  that might be doable.  But not from the browser itself.

Comment: I'm not talking about a webview inside my app
What i need is to access browsing data (cookies, history...) of a mobile phone browser from an installed app on the same device
So this is not possible even with user consent ?

Comment: Not even with user consent.  Even if Google wanted to they couldn't force it to work-  because a user can download a 3rd party web browser like Firefox and it wouldn't store cookies in a way Google can access.  And this is a good thing-  cookies have login tokens.  If you had access to this as a 3rd party app, you'd be able to impersonate me to my bank.  I'm sure you have a perfectly legit usecase for it, but it just is too dangerous a hole to allow access to.